# Invalid date [dd/mm/yyyy] in safari? How to display in dd/mm/yyyy format using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Safari browser gives a syntax error when i try to display the date format in

> dd/mm/yyyy

format. Is there any solution how to display them using jquery? Thanks in advance

```
        function parseDate(input) {
      var d= new Date(input);
      return d.format("dd-mm-yyyy");//"dd/mm/yyyy"
    }//works on chrome not in safari
```

Comment: why not doing it on serverside?

Comment: AFAIK `format()` is not a standard method of the `Date` object. Are you using a plugin or something?

Comment: @Juhana I think OP is using this plugin: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Comment: @dude I've just tried the plugin in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ly4vb/, and it works fine in all browsers - even safari. Could you detail the error message you get.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am getting still the same error "SyntaxError: invalid date (undefined,0)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a quick demo of your example code using the [date format plugin](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format), [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly4vb) and it appears to work fine in Safari.

Things to try:

- Check the format of the date you're passing in to the `input` is a valid date object
- Make sure that the javascript plugin is included in your page correctly, and that an older version is not being cached by Safari.

Failing that, please provide more information about the error Safari gives you.

**UPDATE**

As you've now said you're passing a string to the `Date()` object, I can see the problem. Safari is very strict about what it will accept, so you'll need to parse the string first, to form a valid `Date` object. Try the below:

```
//var d = new Date("2011-11-02"); // This will work for the vast majority of browsers - but not safari

function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
  return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]);
}

var d = parseDate("2011-11-02");
alert(d.format("dd-mm-yyyy"));
```

You can test it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ly4vb/1/

Comment: I am getting this error "SyntaxError: invalid date (undefined,0)"

Comment: That means the plugin is not recognising the date you are passing in as valid. What is the date you're giving it?

Comment: 2011-11-02 this is the format which i give as input but the output in firefox is displayed , problem is with safari

Comment: I assume you're passing that as a string? If so, Safari's `Date()` object is notorisly stringent about the strings it will convert. I'll update my post with a fix.

Comment: i had tried this above one? i get the output as Wed Nov 02 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) but i need 02-11-2011

Comment: That's the response you get from my fiddle too?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4827/discussion-between-dude-and-rory-mccrossan)